# Bind angular cross iframes, possible?

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way you can bind/share the same scope/controllers/directives and stuff into another iframe in the same domain?

would be cool if i could have the same ngApp in another iframe aswell. Has anyone done anything like this before?

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is possible and you don't need to do anything special, you just need to compile the content.

Here is an example: **http://jsfiddle.net/gWgYM/**

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
    <h1>The date is {{date}}</h1>
    <iframe frame=""></iframe>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $scope.date = new Date();
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 1000);
});

app.directive('frame', function( $compile ) {
    return function( $scope, $element ) {
        var $body = angular.element($element[0].contentDocument.body),
            template  = $compile('<p>The date in the iframe is {{date}}</p>')($scope);
        $body.append(template);
    };
});
```