# AngularJS shared service not acting as singleton between modules

Tags: angularjs

I have seen numerous flavors of this question, but cannot seem to find the right answer for my issue.

The problem with the following is the service cannot share data between the other modules/controllers. It does not act as a singleton. Meaning, if I add windows in `dashboard` and call `windowService.getWindows()` I will see the windows I added. But if I do the same from `myWidget` after adding them via the dashboard, or vice versa, the collection in the service is empty as if the other module/controller hasn't added anything. What am I doing wrong here? I expected a single collection of windows to be retained by the service and be accessible from either of my other modules.

Module 1

```
var dashboard = angular.module('dashboard', [windowServiceModule]);
dashboard.controller('DashboardController', function DashboardController(windowService) {...stuff});
```

Module 2

```
var myWidget = angular.module('myWidget', [windowServiceModule]);
myWidget.controller('MyWidgetController', function MyWidgetController(windowService) {...stuff});
```

Service

```
var windowServiceModule = angular.module('windowService', []);
windowServiceModule.service('windowService', function() {
   var windows = [];
   this.addWindow = function(win)
   {
      this.windows.push(win)
   }

   this.getWindows = function()
   {
      return this.windows;
   }
});
```

EDIT: while walking through other answers, I tried this: [Share a single service between multiple angular.js apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725392/share-a-single-service-between-multiple-angular-js-apps)

That exposed a part of the problem, I think. The above suggests iterating over a `$rootScope` collection, but in my case, there is only one `$rootScope` in the collection and it is not the same between `dashboard` and `myWidget`. As it is, `myWidget` is in an iframe and now I'm thinking I need to take a different approach, currently testing a solution similar to the link I left in the comments.

Comment: I believe `var windows = [];` and `this.windows.push` / `this.windows()` are referring to different instances due to the use of `this`. Try removing `this` from `this.windows....`

Comment: Also that should be `return windows;` without the ellipse at the end.

Comment: Ya, trying your first solution now, but the return was correct in my code, I typed up this example instead of copy+pasting because I like working harder and making more mistakes ;)

Comment: It doesn't appear that had any effect. Removing the `this` still results in the same issue. FWIW, I also tried using `this.windows` instead of `var windows`.

Comment: Currently trying a similar thing to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378386/angularjs-using-common-service-in-different-modules

Comment: No luck with the previous solution, currently trying something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318633/access-angularjs-service-from-a-service-inside-a-different-frame

Comment: In regard the the above link, I really wasn't wanting access the other scope, I think I can get that to work, but I was sort of thinking scope wasn't in this equation. I just have the state maintained in the service and update/get it from the modules. This is more like walking the chain back up to the parent and using the state in its scope. Eh, whatever, if it works I'm keeping it, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm pretty sure my initial code would have worked fine if the `myWidget` wasn't being loaded in an iframe. I have a dashboard that can open windows embedded or popped out and I wanted to use the service to manage the windows and handle passing state back and forth since popping out the iframe requires a reload of the page.

Anyways, I now have something like this in place in the service and it is working:

```
var windowServiceModule = angular.module('windowService', []);
windowServiceModule.service('windowService', function($window) {
   ...stuff
   var parentScope = $window.parent.getScope();
   ...other stuff
```

After that you can access anything in the parent's scope with parentScope. I pass in the angular `$window`.

Just for reference, `getScope()` already existed in the parent JSP file. This is what is looks like:

```
function getScope()
{
   return angular.element($("#DashboardController")).scope();
}
```